# How to make multiple select filter in Magento 2 Layered Navigation

Tags: layered-navigation, magento-2.2.5, multiple-select-layered

By default in Magento layered navigation I can select only one option to filter for every attribute.

I have to make custom code which allow to select multiple options from every attribute. So what is the process to achieve this and in which files I have to make changes.

I don't want to use any other modules. I have to make custom code only.

Please help me or give some suggestion.

Comment: Please give me suggestion.

Comment: Did you find something to create this one ?